# When using IFF() function if data is null I will receive don't match

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

When using IFF() function to compare data between 2 tables, source and target, if column has IS NUll value I would receive 'don't match'. Please could you give me advice?

```
   IIF(T1.MBR_STAT  = CAST(T2.MEMSTA_SHORT_NAME AS VARCHAR(10)),'MATCH', 'DON''T MATCH')    AS MBR_STAT_VALIDATION,
```

If data match in column regardless if is an empty string or IS NULL value it should give me 'MATCH' result, if data doesn't match I should receive 'Don't Match'

Comment: iif () is for 2012 >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `coalesce` for null checking and replace null with a value that will never match with compare column value

```
 IF(coalesce(T1.MBR_STAT,'something_')  = CAST(T2.MEMSTA_SHORT_NAME AS VARCHAR(10)),'MATCH', 'DON''T MATCH')    AS MBR_STAT_VALIDATION
```

Comment: IIF? Is that a MySQL function?

Comment: sorry it is sql server 2012  and up

Answer (score 1):

First, I strongly advise you to use `case` rather than `iif()`.  `case` expressions are standard SQL.  `iif()` is for "back" compatibility with MS Access.

Second, you need to be explicit about the `NULL` comparison in SQL Server.  It does not support `NULL`-safe comparisons.  This looks like:

```
(CASE WHEN T1.MBR_STAT = CAST(T2.MEMSTA_SHORT_NAME AS VARCHAR(10))
      THEN 'MATCH'
      WHEN T1.MBR_STAT IS NULL AND T2.MEMSTA_SHORT_NAME IS NULL
      THEN 'MATCH'
      ELSE 'DON''T MATCH'
 END) AS MBR_STAT_VALIDATION,
```

I also find it strange that you are using `CAST()` for this purpose when there is a very  nice function `LEFT()` that is simpler and makes the logic clearer:

```
(CASE WHEN T1.MBR_STAT = LEFT(T2.MEMSTA_SHORT_NAME, 10)
      THEN 'MATCH'
      WHEN T1.MBR_STAT IS NULL AND T2.MEMSTA_SHORT_NAME IS NULL
      THEN 'MATCH'
      ELSE 'DON''T MATCH'
 END) AS MBR_STAT_VALIDATION,
```

Comment: Thank you for tips @Gordon Linoff and your answear.

Comment: And actually on the end I used CASE statment and compared data between columns, as you have suggested. What would be appropriate usage of IIF()  beside of "back" compatibility?

Comment: @DKCroat . . . I can't think of any.  Functionally, `case` is more general and standard.  There could be some nuances, such as the exact type that returned by the expression or whether the `else` clause is evaluated if the condition is true.

Comment: thank you so much for clarification. Sometimes I am just playing around trying to find most efficient way to validate data through SQL  queries/scripts. However, very helpful hints from you!